# Switch user to root GUI and return

Tags: permissions, login, firefox, thunderbird

For many tasks, I find sudo too cumbersome.  I also authorized root to have a standard window manager Xwindow GUI session to which I get by the switch user from my ordinary user Xwindow MATE GUI session.  When I do so, I get the standard login GUI screen from 20.04 LTS, and login as root.  There are two choices for environment:  MATE and Ubuntu.  MATE does not work as of this writing, Ubuntu does.  At the end of my root GUI session, I logout.  Rather than taking me directly back to the user session from which I did the switch user, again the standard Ubuntu GUI login screen appears, not an "unlock" screen.  The login screen in this case is an "unlock" in fact as once I enter my password, I am returned to the GUI (MATE) in the state at which I did the initial switch user.  Is there a setting/configuration file edit, etc., that will allow the return after the logout from the root user environment -- to which I had switched -- that does not require a password to get back to the environment from which I had done the switch user? Take care. Stay safe.

Comment: @Nmath I was not aware that there were two very different "Edit" commands on this interface.  This should be clearly documented and perhaps it is, but I could not find it.  Is the rewriting of the initial question now more clear?  A question about assumption:  should I assume that the reader is a computer science and engineering working "degreed" professional, or much closer to an "end-user" or information technologist?  On the SL users list, the first CSE assumption was correct, although many questions were posed by SL users who were more end-users or IT.

Comment: @Nmath It is not possible to show "exactly what you see on the screen" unless an image file (e.g., a screen shot file in PNG format) can be attached, but this does not seem possible.  If the issue is in a plain CLI, than a copy and paste of CLI text would suffice.  Descriptions of what one sees often are in the eye of the beholder, which is why going back to at least Word Perfect end-user use documentation "screen shots" were supplied.  To be 100% reproducible and unambiguous, one needs to provide detailed specification on the physical platform as well as the specific software versions.

Comment: @Nmath  On most unixes (Linux, what was the original from ATT and now otherwise licensed, and BSD versions), there is a Xwindow GUI application terminal CLI (I should have stated GUI Terminal CLI), GUI terminals that are not CLIs but emulations of the various graphic modes of a VTxxx/Tektronix, etc., and also a combination of keystrokes plus Fn (typically at least F3), the upper function keys on a "PC" keyboard, that leads to a full terminal CLI, not under a GUI, usually with an CLI login text prompt.  This ambiguity is why I was specific.